# Comparing two time periods using getTime not working

Tags: java, datetime, time

I'm a newbie to Java. I am given 3 times, in the "HH:mm:ss" format. I'm supposed to take an input(in integers(and must be in minutes)) add it to the 3rd time. If the sum of time is less than the 1st and 2nd time(1st time <=2nd time), it must print 1. If it is only less than the 2nd time, it should print 2. If neither is less, it prints false.

However, the values of the double variable I'm mapping the date to are returning
values in the negative sometimes (Please check the output).

Could someone help me understand why? Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class TimeTrial2 {
    public static void main(String q[]) throws ParseException
    {
    Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);

    SimpleDateFormat y=new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
    SimpleDateFormat k=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    String b=x.nextLine();
    Date c=k.parse(b);//1st Time
    String d=x.nextLine();
    Date e=k.parse(d);//2nd Time
    String f=x.nextLine();
    Date g=k.parse(f);//Time to be added to the input
    int a=x.nextInt();//Input time i
    a=a/60;

    Date z=y.parse(Integer.toString(a));
    double p=(z.getTime()+g.getTime()); 
    double r=c.getTime();
    double s=e.getTime();

    System.out.println(p+"\n"+r+"\n"+s); `//to check the values of p,r and s`
    if(r>=p)
    {
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    else if(s>=p)
    {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("FALSE!");
    }
}

}
```

**Input**:

4:30:00

6:00:00

4:00:00

60

**This is my output**:

-2.16E7

-3600000.0

1800000.0

1

Edit: Adding 330 minutes (+5:30 GMT) rectifies the issue.
However, I'd recommend using Ole V.V's answer as it is much easier. I was unaware that such a date class and method existed. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Asking us to debug your code is not a question, refer [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why are you using `double ` when getTime returns `long`?

Comment: Today would be an excellent day for you to learn to use the debugger that came packaged with your IDE.

Comment: long is returning the same values in the int form. Why is this happening?

Comment: Read [Date documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) Date.getTime `Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.`. Use `long`, not `double` or `int`

Comment: I'm aware that the method getTume returns the number of milliseconds since January 1,1970. However, I have no use of the date. All I'm concerned with is the time. Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: The `Date` class that you are using isn’t really suited for the job. `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome. And both are long outdated. I recommend you look into [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its [`LocalTime` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). The modern API is also so much nicer to work with.

Comment: When posting code to Stack Overflow and asking us to read and understand it, could you think of more explanatory variable names, please?

Comment: @OleV.V.: Will make sure that I name  the variables correctly. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TimeTrial3 {

    public static void main(String... commandLineArguments) {
        Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss");

        String time1String = consoleInput.nextLine();
        LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse(time1String, timeFormatter);
        String time2String = consoleInput.nextLine();
        LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse(time2String, timeFormatter);
        if (time2.isBefore(time1)) {
            System.err.println("First time must be before or equal to second time, they were"
                    + time1 + " and " + time2);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String timeToAddString = consoleInput.nextLine();
        LocalTime timetoAdd = LocalTime.parse(timeToAddString, timeFormatter);
        int minutesToAdd = consoleInput.nextInt();
        LocalTime timeToCompare = timetoAdd.plusMinutes(minutesToAdd);
        if (timeToCompare.isBefore(time1))
        {
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        else if (timeToCompare.isBefore(time2))
        {
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }

}
```

### Issues with your code

- The `Date` class isn’t very well suited for representing a time of day only.
- The `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes are long outdated and the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. I recommend you don’t use them at all. Instead I am using and warmly recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.
- When you can use library classes for dates and/or times, do that. Don’t use `double` nor `long`.
- An observation, not really a problem: It seems you are in a time zone at offset -05:30 from UTC (like Sri Lanka or India)? For example, your input of `4:30:00` was parsed into this time on January 1, 1970 (the epoch day) at offset -5:50, which is equal to 1 hour before the epoch, so it came out as -3600000.0 because -3600 seconds equals -1 hour. This is not a problem in itself as long as all your times are at the same offset. Then you can still compare them using `before` or `after` as harsha kumar Reddy said in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188930/5772882).
- The trouble comes when you try to add the milliseconds from two `Date` objects. The third time, 4:00:00, is parsed into 1 hour 30 min before the epoch, and the 60 minutes into 4 hours 30 minutes before the epoch. When adding the two you expect a time of 5:00:00 (in your time zone). Instead you get 6 hours before the epoch, which is printed as `-2.16E7` (on my computer I get a different incorrect result because I am in a different time zone).
- By dividing the minutes from input by 60 to obtain hours, you are losing precision. For example, if the input was 90 minutes (one and a half hours), you get just 1 hour after division.
- And as mentioned in the comment, you should use explanatory variable names. You may have had an idea behind the names you chose, but I didn’t get it.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed explanation. This is really insightful. One thing, to rectify the time zone offset, could I just add the difference between the UTC and IST(my time zone) ?

Comment: If you wanted to do that, I believe you should set each formatter’s time zone to UTC through its `setTimeZone` method. It sounds like it would work, no guarantees. One potential disadvantage would be that if you print your `Date` objects, the output will be confusing because their `toString` method will still use your local time zone.

Comment: But I don’t understand why you mind using the modern and much better classes. And in any case, using a `Date`, a point in time, to represent 60 minutes to be added, is conceptually incorrect and bound to confuse anyone trying to read your code.

Comment: I don't. As said, I'm a newbie to Java and was given this problem by our trainer to solve by self. I was told that this problem could be solved by SimpleDateFormat. However, your method of solving has proved to be much easier. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sorry if I was helping too much by providing working code. I didn't intend to spoil it and take your learning away from you, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Consider how you add the time to the Date. I tried out the following code for adding minutes to the date and it worked.

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(g);
calendar.add(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, a);
```

Input:

```
g = 5:00:00
a = 40
```

Output:

```
Thu Jan 01 05:00:00 IST 1970
Thu Jan 01 05:40:00 IST 1970
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `equals() , before() , after()` methods of Date class .

refer java Api docs